# How to list Azure Storage Containers and Blobs

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I'm new to Azure Storage and I think I may be misunderstanding a few of the concepts.

I'd like to list all my Storage Containers and Blobs using PowerShell.

I can list all my Storage Accounts using the following code:

```
Get-AzureStorageAccount | Select StorageAccountName, GeoPrimaryLocation
```

Each of the Storage Accounts has a Container. How do I get it? I don't see a command that lists Containers.
There is a Get-AzureStorageContainer command, but it doesn't take a Storage Account as input.

What am I missing?

-- Edit --

I see that I can do the following:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName myStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey xxx
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container myContainer
```

Why is the context required?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806407.aspx - from what I read, context is not required.  What do you get if you just enter the get commands?

Comment: I get an error if I omit the context. Get-AzureStorageContainer : BadRequest: The name is not a valid storage account name. Storage account names must be between 
3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only.
At C:\Users\MatthewFitzmaurice\Documents\Scripts\Move VHDs.ps1:7 char:1
+ Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name vhds
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageContainer], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CloudException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageContainerC

Comment: Looks like the context is similar to credentials.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I am able to list containers using `New-AzureStorageContext` and `Get-AzureStorageContainers`.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <name> -StorageAccountKey <key>

Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx
```

Answer (score 15):

With the new `Az` module, you need to do the following

```
Import-Module Az
$azStorageAccountName = "" # Name of your storage account 
$azStorageAccountKey = "" # Access key for your storage account
$azContainerName = "" # Container name to list your blobs
$azResourceGroupName = "" # Resource group name where storage account lives

$connectionContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $azResourceGroupName -AccountName $azStorageAccountName).Context
# Get a list of containers in a storage account
Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $azContainerName -Context $connectionContext | Select Name
# Get a list of blobs in a container 
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $azContainerName -Context $connectionContext | Select Name
```

Comment: This is perfect. Just a quick change to the command to list all containers in a storage account
```Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $connectionContext```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $azContainerName -Context $connectionContext | Select Name`that is $azContainerName rather than $azStorageAccountName?

Answer (score 3):

## List all containers

```
Get-AzureStorageContainer
```

## List all blobs in a container.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName
```

There is also a complete Getting Started Guide for PowerShell and Azure Storage which you can find here. [Azure Storage PowerShell Getting Started](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it within ARM:

```
function Get-StorageContainer
{
    param
    (
        [string]$StorageAccountName
    )

    $StorageAccounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount

    $selectedStorageAccount = $StorageAccounts | where-object{$_.StorageAccountName -eq $StorageAccountName}
    $key1 = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $selectedStorageAccount.ResourceGroupName -name $selectedStorageAccount.StorageAccountName)[0].value

    $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $selectedStorageAccount.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key1
    $storageContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $storageContext
    $storageContainer
}

Get-StorageContainer -StorageAccountName storageaccount
```

Comment: What does New-AzureStorageContext do in this example? I just can't figure it out and it is not in the main documentation of Azure storage account. Microsoft manages to create random complexity everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-AzAccount

Write-Host "Gathering container Public access level information...`n"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$saUsage = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription <# -subscriptionid "6f3ecdd5-6sff85-4sss9b-a9ec-0a7sds2ad6" #>

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions)  {
    Write-Host $subscription.Id
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionObject $subscription

    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount

    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        #list containers
        $storages = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.StorageAccountName

        $ctx = $storageAccount.Context

        $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx

        foreach($container in $containers){
            $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                SubscriptionName = $subscription.Name
                StorageAccount = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
                ContainerName = $container.Name
                ContainerPublicAccess = $container.PublicAccess
            }
            $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails)) | Out-Null  
            Write-Host "object written to list"
        }
    }
}
$saUsage | Export-Csv -Path C:\Containers_Access_Level.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).